# Why do the curved edges not work for me in networkx?

Tags: python, networkx

So I want to have curved edges and according to the [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges.html) it seems to be super easy as I can just define the `connectionstyle`. So I tried to set up a minimum example like this:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

B = np.random.rand(5, 5)
G = nx.DiGraph(B)
A = nx.minimum_spanning_arborescence(G) # creating some arborescence, i.e. a directed graph

pos = nx.spring_layout(A)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(A, pos, node_size=300)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(A, pos, connectionstyle='arc3, rad=0.2')
```

Comment: I tried your code and it gives graph with curved edges. If you are not getting it, can you show your plot?

Comment: Yes, I do not get any curves- is it maybe an old version of networkx then? Wait I upload my graph

Comment: https://ibb.co/b3vV0F7 Here you go

Comment: I'm using `networkx==2.4 & matplotlib==3.1.2` as reference. Check your versions and try to match it if you have older ones.